# Length of a boundary of union of unit balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Consider $X$ to be a compact set in $[0,5]^2\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Assume that $X$ is a union of translations of a unit ball. Then prove that $\partial X$ has a length bounded by $C$ where $C$ is independent of $X$.

Comment: Where did you find this question?

Comment: I saw the problem 3.C (iv) in the book From Euclid to Alexandrov; a guided tour - 
A. Petrunin, A. Yashinski. But to solve the problem I believe that the above problem may be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Fix small $\epsilon>0$. We shall show that the union of balls with center in a given ball of radius $\epsilon$ must have bounded perimeter. Note each ball $D_i$ has boundary expressible as a polar graph $$r=f_i(\theta)$$ where $f_i$ are uniformly bounded and uniformly Lipschitz. Then the boundary of $\cup_iD_i$ is given by the polar graph $$r=\sup_if_i(\theta)$$ which has bound and Lipschitz norm depending only on $\epsilon$, and hence length $L(\epsilon)$ depending only on $\epsilon$ (by the polar arc length formula from calculus).
2. Cover $[0,5]^2$ with balls $B_1,
   \dots, B_{N(\epsilon)}$ of radius $\epsilon$. In each $B_j$, let $X_j$ be the the set of balls contributing to $X$ with center in $B_j$. Then the length of $\partial X$ can be (not very sharply) bounded by $$\mathrm{length\,\, of\,\,} \partial X\le\sum_{j=1}^{N(\epsilon)}\mathrm{length\,\, of\,\,} \partial X_j\le N(\epsilon)L(\epsilon).$$

This can be optimized a bit by choosing the right $\epsilon$, but it is still an extremely weak bound as we are throwing away much of the boundary we compute.